# How to login to Picasa

Tags: android, picasa

I have only found fragments, unsupported code, or google alpha libraries to login to Picasa. 
Anyone know where I can find a more complete example? Ideally without dependencies on half the universe? Something like the facebook SDK.

Or should I install the picasa app? If so -- where can I find an example of how to log in from my app using the picasa app?